# Рекурсивная функция на практике. Erlang

Tags: функции, рекурсия, функциональное-программирование, erlang

Объясните пожалуйста суть рекурсии и хвостовой рекурсии в Erlang. Только не на примере вычисления факториала, а например на зайцах :-) То есть на практическом примере.
Дополню. Если можно привести простой пример (можно ссылку) практической рекурсивной функции которая считает допустим тех же зайцев с комментариями и той же функции с хвостовой рекурсией (тоже желательно с комментариями)

Comment: Последовательность Фибоначчи - это идеализированная модель разрастания популяции бессмертных кроликов. Чем вам не объяснение "на зайцах"? :)

Comment: Я имел в виду что прошу показать не на примере вычисления какого-то абстрактного числа/чисел а на примере реальной функции работающей над выполнением практической задачи...

Comment: Я бы еще понял, если бы вы попросили пример рекурсии в каком-нибудь `C` или `Pascal`, где рекурсия не обязательна, ведь есть циклы. Но в `Erlang` циклов нет, есть **только** рекурсия, и пройти мимо нее у вас просто не получится в любой задаче сложнее hello world. Начните учить язык и с первых же часов столкнетесь со всевозможными примерами рекурсии.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Зайцы, так зайцы!

Давайте посчитаем через сколько поколений сколько зайцев у вас будет. :)

С Erlang мне работать не приходилось, но я думаю вы и так всё поймете. Всё очень просто

```
<?php
// В функцию передаем сколько поколений надо посчитать
// и сколько зайцев есть изначально.
function countRabbits(int $generationCount, int $countOfRabbits):int {
    $countOfChildren = 7;
    // Произведем простейший расчет.
    // Одна пара зайцев производит указанное выше кол-во детей.
    $result =  ((int)($countOfRabbits / 2)) * $countOfChildren;
    //Вычтем уже посчитанное поколение
    $generationCount--;
    //Если дальше считать не надо, то отдадим результат не забыв про родителей
    if ($generationCount === 0) {
        return $result + $countOfRabbits;
    }

    // Если посчитаны ещё не все покаления то вызовем новый подсчет
    // с кол-вом поколением уменьшеным на единицу и получившимся кол-вом детей.
    // Также не забудем, что нужно учесть родителей при возврате
    return countRabbits($generationCount, $result) + $countOfRabbits;
}

// Будем считать что у вас есть два зайца и вы хотите посчитать 4 поколения
echo countRabbits(4,2);
```

Вот что произойдет:

```
countRabbits(4,2) посчитает что у двух родителей будет 7 детей и вызовет countRabbits(3, 7)
    countRabbits(3, 7) посчитает что у 7 родителей будет 21 детей и вызовет countRabbits(2, 21)
        countRabbits(2, 21) посчитает что у 21 родителей будет 70 детей и вызовет countRabbits(1, 70)
            countRabbits(1, 70) посчитает что у 70 родителей будет 245 детей и
            вернет 245 + 70 = 315
        вернет 315 + 21 = 336
    вернет 336 + 7 = 343
вернет 343 + 2 = 345
```

Итого мы посчитали что у вас будет 345 зайцев. :)

Что же касается хвостовой рекурсии, то это всего лишь значит, что рекурсивная функция должна возвращать значение именно **себя** в вызванной в рекурсии. Т.е. если взять наш пример и просто перестать учитывать зайцев-родителей и возвращать:

```
return countRabbits($generationCount, $result);
```

Либо не исключать зайцев-родителей из дальнейшего размножения:

```
return countRabbits($generationCount, $result + $countOfRabbits);
```

То это уже и есть **Хвостовая рекурсия**. Единственное чем хороша такая рекурсия это то, что многие ЯП автоматически преобразовывают её в цикл, что позволяет избежать утечек памяти.

Хорошего вам дня! :)